# Debug mode only works sending email in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

i wrote a sending email function that only works on my debug mode(debug local server) when i publishing and hosting C# code that function doesn't work. This is my email configuration function

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="admin@XXXX.com">
                <network host="smtp.XXXXX.com" port="25"
                         userName="admin@XXXXX.com" password="XXXXX" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
```

Comment: Have you supplied the correct credentials for sending an email from the particular location that you have deployed the application?

Comment: Are you logging the exceptions that occur when you are attempting to send an email from the published location?

If so, what does the error log say specifically
This is generally an SMTPException, catch it and let us know.

Comment: Provide more information please. What error, if any, are you getting when you run the code in your published environment?

Answer (score 4):

I have found a lot of times that there can be a firewall or antivirus (with built in firewall) blocking outgoing smtp traffic. You may also want to check with the network administrator that the mail server will allow smtp traffic from the server you are sending from.

Comment: +1 to this. My place of work has all computers blocking outbound smtp traffic with only Microsoft Outlook as an exception.

Comment: Trying a telnet to port 25 on the mail server is a simple first troubleshooting step.